# View in Mysql crashes the DB

Tags: mysql

Our DB crashed (mysql 5.2) and the reason when i looked was

```
show create table <view_name>
```

This was not logged as a slow query, but was a pointer value in the crash debug. I really can't understand this, can a view in the DB crash the DB?

Although i can think of removing this view and test, it will be helpful if any of one faced this kind of scenario, its better to know to the reason than hide the reason.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE `view_name`

where view_name  is  a view existing in the DB.

Comment: How can a DB crash? You mean db server crashed? Or data in DB became incosistent?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using 5.2?

You may want to review this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52685).  Does the View reference any tables that no longer exist?

Comment: It seems its 5.0, do you think this needs to be upgraded?

Comment: That depends on a lot.  I believe moving to 5.1.47 makes a lot of sense for any basic MySQL App, however it really depends on your app.  My guess is this is a bug you are seeing, most likely due to the view missing the underlying tables.